# Limits of Finite Sums

Tags: calculus

I need to take the limit of a finite sum for the purpose of finding the area under a curve.

The function is $f(x) = \sqrt{49-x^2}$. From here I made the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1nf\left(\frac{k}n\right)$

This gives me the sum: $\sum_{k = 1}^n  \frac{1}n\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}$

I remove the constant and get $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{49-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}$

From here, I believe I need to isolate it to $k^2$ so that I can apply the formula for sums of squares. But I don't know how to get rid of the square root.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you typed up the math in your question using $\LaTeX$. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Also, where did the square root come from?

Comment: Did you want $f(x)=\sqrt{49-x^2}$? It doesn't quite makes sense if $f(x)=49-x^2$...

Comment: There is probably not much if an obvious way to solve this, since it is the Reimann sum for $\int_{0}^7 \sqrt{49-x^2}dx$, so the limit should be the area of a quarter of a quarter circle with radius $7$ - that is $\frac{49\pi}{4}$.

Comment: What a mistake! Yes. That is the function (corrected above).

Comment: Why 49pi/4 and not 2?